# On selecting a option it should take me to required page with the marked values

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I was working in a real-estate website.  *Header and footer are common* among all the pages.  In home page i am submitting a form to search result page where the results will be displayed.  I kept an option in the header like luxurious properties and myself assigning the values to the field and submitting to the same page.  Once user clicks i was calling one `javascript` function where i was assigning values on my own and submitting the form.  When this is done from home page it works.  Say i am in contact us page and i want to view luxurious properties, it want me to take to the search result page.  That time there is no fields in the contact us page.  In that case how can i submit the values to the search result page?? I was working with `PHP`. Here is the sample image of the option in the Header.

Here is my code what i am doing.,

```
function checkCities()
        {
            var userCity = $.cookie('UserCityName');
            if(userCity != null)
            {
                     document.getElementById('cboPropertyTypeRes').value =  'Flats';
                     document.getElementById('cboBedroomsRes').value = '4';
                     document.getElementById('cboMinimumBudgetRes').value = '10000000';
                     document.getElementById('cboMaximumBudgetRes').value = 'Above 2 Crore';
                     $('#frmSearchProperty').submit();
           }
        }
```

[image]

Hope my question is clear.  Answers would be appreciable.  Thanks in Advance.!!!

Comment: Please provide some code to help you with.

Comment: @SankalpMishra: Kindly check it out.

Comment: Just for clarification.. After you check the radio button in the home page and manually (using a button) to submit the form? is that right? and you are trying to do the same in contact page where there is no submit button. Kindly clarify to help you..

Comment: No Ji.  There is a form in home page and i can submit it my selecting the values. or if you need luxurious properties you can select that option and it will submit a form for you with predefied characters.  I am trying to submit the same from any part of the website.